# Pass array of objects by reference and save the actual array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc, web

I am passing an array to a function. Since, in javascript, 
arrays by default get passed by reference I tried to make a copy of array. But in the end,  the operations performed in function effects the actual array data.

All I want to do is save the actual state of an array.

Here is my code :

```
let  arrcopy =new Array( items.dt);
citem = binarySearch(arrcopy[0], ind.ItemID);
```

Comment: My glassball's best guess is you want to deep copy an array, but from the code and text given, i can't really be sure at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes i want a deep copy of an array i am using an object array of items sending those to binary search method

Comment: when i get result from method there is only one item remaining in orignal items array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stingify(items.dt))
```

this has made my work

Answer (score 0):

You means you want to preserve the original array as it is (you want to preserve immutability)?

Then use **reduce** method.

```
    const test = (arr) => {
    return arr.reduce((result, val) => {
       // do the needful here
      result.push(val);
      return result;
    }, []);
}
```

expect(arr).to.be.equal(result); => will return false as the original array won't be updated

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create array as copy with [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
let  arrcopy = Object.assign([],items.dt);
citem = binarySearch(arrcopy[0], ind.ItemID);
```

Or just **ES6** way with destruction/spread operator is enough

```
let arrcopy = [...items.dt];
```